# API only returns responses with no content

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

My methods only return responses with no content.

Controller

```
[HttpGet("Floors/{floorId}", Name = "FloorById")]
public IActionResult GetFloor(int floorId)
{
    try
    {
        Floor floor = _repository.Floor.GetFloor(floorId);
        if (floor == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(floor);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "text");
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public Floor GetFloor(int floorId)
{
    return _context.Floors.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == floorId);
}
```

Ideally, this code should return an Ok response with the object as well.

Instead, I only get an Ok response when using swagger. Not even the NotFound.

Comment: how is the controller action called?

Comment: @Fildor that solves the issue of nothing getting returned with Ok(), but my NotFound still doesn't get picked up by swagger ui. Could you please explain when I should use IActionResult vs ActionResult?

Comment: @Nkosi I don't understand the question.

Comment: Where are you getting the Ok response? How are you calling the action that return only Ok response

Comment: @Nkosi I just now started using swagger ui to test my api. Apparently, I did lots of bad stuff round here. https://imgur.com/a/w4opMXR here's an example. Here's the actual GetFloor method: https://imgur.com/a/rPqvBb4

Comment: No you basically left out important details about what is being done so it was difficult for us to identify the actual issue. This is a swagger issue where it cannot determine the response type. Add an attribute to indicate to swagger what type to expect

Comment: When I said I did bad stuff, I meant about my API. I just noticed it's unable to add entities to the database. xD How would I add attributes to tell swagger what to expect?

Comment: Btw, apart of swagger you can use Postman. For GET requests a browser may also be easier.

Comment: You don't need the try-catch as the infrastructure will automatically return error 500 when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger is unable to determine what type the action returns based on the `IActionResult`.

Use the `ProducesResponseType` attribute:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Floor), 200)] // <-- THIS
[HttpGet("Floors/{floorId}", Name = "FloorById")]
public IActionResult GetFloor(int floorId) {
    try {
        Floor floor = _repository.Floor.GetFloor(floorId);
        if (floor == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(floor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return StatusCode(500, "text");
    }
}
```